# Substring in C Shell not working as intended

Tags: shell, csh

I'm trying to extract the file name without the extension from a directory full of files. Here is the code that I'm using:

```
foreach file (*)
     set extPos=`echo $file | awk '{print index($0,".")}'`
     set fname = `echo $file | awk '{print substr($0,0,$extPos)}'`
     echo $file
     echo $extPos
     echo $fname
end
```

And these are the results I'm receiving:

```
hodorrr.png
8

testfile1.txt
10

testfile2.txt
10

testfile3.txt
10

wtf.tiff
4
```

So as you can see the substrings are blank, does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 1):

The usage of substr can be confusing and inconsistent with other versions of substr.

To fix your immediate problem, try

```
set fname = `echo $file | awk '{print substr($0,1,'"$extPos"')}'`
```

To eliminate the relatively expensive calculation of $extPos with multiple processes, you can get `fname` from `file` all in 1 awk process with

```
file=testfile1.txt
#not needed set extPos=`echo $file | awk '{print index($0,".")}'`
set fname = `echo $file | awk '{print substr($0,1,index($0,".")-1)}'`

echo "fname=" $fname
testfile1
```

So note that substr doesn't use `0` for it's address for the first position in a string (but uses `1` (thank you awk gods!;-)  AND that you can nest function calls (like `index()`) inside the parameter list of another function.

---

Of course the usual warnings like **friends don't let friend code in csh** still apply, but sometime organization inertia is too much to overcome!

IHTH

Comment: Unfortunately it's required for the class I'm taking :/ Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you don't need `awk`. `csh` has built-in features to extract the root or extension from a file name.

```
% foreach file ( this.txt that.dat another.blah )
foreach? echo "file = '$file', root = '$file:r', extension = '$file:e'"
foreach? end
file = 'this.txt', root = 'this', extension = 'txt'
file = 'that.dat', root = 'that', extension = 'dat'
file = 'another.blah', root = 'another', extension = 'blah'
%
```

The modifiers are documented in the `tcsh` man page under **History substitution**, but they also apply to variable substitution.

(If you decide to switch to bash, it has similar features, but they're not quite as convenient.)